# Merging different resolution DEMs in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, mosaic-dataset

I have 4 DEMs I would like to merge/mosaic together into 1 - each have a different cell size. I am using ArcMap 10.6.1

Things to note:
 - All have 1 band
 - There is 1m, 2m, 5m & 10m DEMs
 - There are no overlaps between the DEMs

I have tried to use the "Moasic to new Raster" tool but got a "999999" error.

Comment: "Moasic to new Raster" is the correct tool to use.  What settings are you using?  Please provide more information about how you are using the tool.

Comment: Do all the rasters have the same pixel depth and datatype?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. This was a duplicate question and the thread @ahmadhanb mentioned was the solution I was looking for.